# Breakdown of reduce function

Tags: scala, reduce

I currently have:

```
x.collect()  
# Result: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

val a = x.reduce((x,y) => x+1) 
# a: Int = 6

val b = x.reduce((x,y) => y + 1)
# b: Int = 12
```

I have tried to follow what has been said here (http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) but still don't quite understand what the individual operations are that lead to these answers.

Could anyone please explain the steps being taken here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the function `(x, y) => x + 1` is not associative.  `reduce` [requires](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@reduce(f:(T,T)=%3ET):T) an associative function.  This is necessary to avoid indeterminacy when combining results across different partitions.

Comment: Since OP didn't mention Spark I would suggest more relevant link: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#reduce[A1>:A](op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1

Comment: @VictorMoroz I'm assuming OP is talking about Spark because of `x.collect()` (with no arguments).

Comment: as a matter of fact; this operation IS associative, so it will always give the same result for a given array: the first element plus the number of elements minus 1. However, it is not the same as the function `(x, y) => y + 1`, which is also associative, but simply has different values (if you used `+` and `*`, you would not expect to have the same result, would you ?).

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Please explain.  Perhaps I have been away from pure math for too long (though it has only been one year), but how is `(x, y) => x + 1` associative?  This holds when `(x * y) * z = x * (y * z)` if and only if `(x + 1) * z = x + 1` if and only if `(x + 1) + 1 = x + 1`, which is obviously not true.

Comment: @dmdmdmdmd, you're completely right, sorry. I must have been really tired when I wrote this. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the `reduce()` method as grabbing two elements from the collection, applying them to a function that results in a new element, and putting that new element back in the collection, replacing the two it grabbed. This is done repeatedly until there is only one element left.  In other words, that previous result is going to get re-grabbed until there are no more previous results.

So you can see where `(x,y) => x+1` results in a new value (x+1) which would be different from `(x,y) => y+1`. Cascade that difference through all the iterations and ...